# Sdl 1.2 with raspberry pi

Tags: c++, sdl, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Is it possible for me to get the SDL libraries for the Raspbian OS? I am thinking about getting a raspberry pi and want to know if I can install SDL for game dev. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

How about:

`sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev`

It's working on my Pi.